# Was bedeutet "abgespaced" in diesem Lied?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

> Ich musste dich überzeugen das du es besser lässt Valezka meinte nur:
>   Langsam ist Ekrem abgespaced

Was bedeutet das Wort *abgespaced*? Stammt dieses Wort aus dem Englischen?
Oder ist das ist Slang, der von Rappern in Deutschland verwendet wird?

Comment: Aus welchem Lied kommen diese Songtexte?

Comment: Das Urteil von Eko Fresh

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Es geht darum, dass Eko Fresh arrogant ist und gleichzeitig eine verzerrte Sicht auf die Welt hat.

Das Wort stammt vom Englischen "space" für dt. "Weltraum", hat aber als Verb nichtmal mehr ein direktes englisches Gegenstück.
Die Idee ist, dass jemand, der im Weltraum ist, also "spaced", weltfremd geworden ist. Die Vorsilbe "ab-" ist dann an das Verb "spacen" angefügt, um anzudeuten, dass der Vorgang abgeschlossen, nicht mehr rückgängig zu machen ist, vgl. "fahren" -> "abfahren", "drehen" -> "abdrehen". "Abgedreht" wäre hier auch ein Wort, mit dem "abgespaced" sinngemäß ersetzbar wäre.

Anmerkung zur Grammatik: Das "-ge-" tritt zwischen Vorsilbe und Werbstamm, da es sich um Partizipien der Vergangenheit handelt. Im gleichen Zuge tritt normalerweise auch ein "t" ans Wortende; allerdings ist es bei aus dem englischen entlehnten Partizipien üblich, dass Leute beim Schreiben das End-"d" der analogen englischen Form beibehalten. Korrekterweise würde man eigentlich im Englischen "spaced" schreiben und im Deutschen "gespacet".

Comment: Spacige Erklärung! :)

Comment: Ist abgespaced das selbe wie "geil" ?

Comment: Geil hat mehr eine positive Bedeutung. "Abgefahren" (um bei den erwähnten Worten zu bleiben) wäre umgangssprachlich da näher dran."Abgedreht" und "abgespacet" gehen in Richtung "wahnsinnig".

Comment: "Abgespacet" lässt sich als Steigerung von "abgehoben" sehen.

Answer (score 2):

"abgespaced" – ist mir schon mal begegnet. Zuerst waren mir die Bedeutung und das Bild nicht klar. Aber bei längerem Nachdenken verstand ich dann die Bedeutung: vom Boden der Realität abgehoben. Ich stelle mir da einen Menschen im Kosmos vor, der durch irgendein Missgeschick von seinem Raumschiff langsam in den Weltraum schwebt und rettungslos verloren ist. In der neuen Wortbildung steckt natürlich englisch space Raum, Weltraum drin und "ab-" löst die Assoziation abdriften, abtreiben aus. Also wäre die Idee der Wortbildung "in den Weltraum abgedriftet". – Ein etwas unschöner Anglizismus, wie er wohl nur unter der jungen Generation zurzeit in Mode ist. Ich bin sicher, dass viele Deutsche das Wort noch nicht einmal gehört haben, geschweige denn verstehen.

Comment: Ich bin zwar auch nicht mehr der Jüngste, aber ich habe dieses Wort schon mehrfach gehört. Es dürfte so in den 90er Jahren entstanden sein und mein subjektiver Eindruck ist, das es schon wieder aus der Mode gekommen ist.

Comment: Vielleicht habe ich zu wenig Kontakt mit der jungen Generation. Könnte durchaus sein, dass das Wort schon wieder aus der Mode kommt. Könnte mir denken, wenn die Leute, die das Wort benutzen, gefragt werden, was das heißt und woher der komische Ausdruck kommt, dann sind sie überfordert. Und vielleicht gibt man es dann auf, solche Ausdrücke zu benutzen.

Comment: ...oder die Ausdrücke, die die Jugend heute benutzt sind noch viel abgespaceter ;)

Comment: Merke schon, du hast diese Art von Jugendjargon besser drauf als ich.

Comment: Obwohl Anglizismenskeptiker gebe ich zu bedenken, dass "abgeräumt" oder "abgeallt" weniger verständlich wären.

Comment: Ist doch ganz klar, was das heißt. Denkt nur an Major Tom:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ql4kaofJ02c  Vöööölliiig losgeeelöööööst!  :D